# mongodb: exclude documents that contain a particular attribute during query

Tags: mongodb

- I have a mongo collection with data as follows:

  - (userid, orgid, some_attr)

    - g@gmail.com, 12345, 'xxxxxx'
  - Same collection also contains:

    - (orgid, some_attr)

      - 12345, 'yyyyy'

Now when I am updating data I may query on (userid, orgid) or (orgid).

My issue is:

when I update using query `(orgid)`, it finds the record with userid and updates that. I dont want that.

How can I query on `(orgid)` but exclude all documents which contains

```
(userid, orgid).
```

For eg:

when I query `{ orgid : 12345 }` it should only return `{ 12345, 'yyyyy' }` and not

```
{ 'g@gmail.com' , 12345, 'xxxxx' }
```

Please provide pointers.

Comment: Got the answer:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13117381/how-to-exclude-from-search-results-documents-with-fields-which-are-not-present-i

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/exists/

Change your query:

```
{ orgid : 12345, userid: {$exists: false} }
```