# mongo.db update for date fields which may or may not have values

Tags: javascript, mongodb

- I have a mongoDB which contains a Date field `updated_at`.
- This field may or may **not** have values.

Now, I want to run a `mongoDB` `update` query which:

- Should update all documents where `updated_at < someDate`
- Should update all documents where `updated_at is not present`.

In a test javascript, I found **date comparison** with `undefined` variables does not yield expected results. Hence, I ask this question.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13117381/how-to-exclude-from-search-results-documents-with-fields-which-are-not-present-i

Comment: I went with this answer in comment above.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you have a documents like below:

```
db.col.save({});
db.col.save({ updated_at: null });
db.col.save({ updated_at: undefined });
db.col.save({ updated_at: ISODate("2018-05-29T00:00:00.000Z") });
db.col.save({ updated_at: ISODate("2018-06-02T00:00:00.000Z") });
```

Assuming you want to update documents `1-4` you can use following update:

```
db.col.update({ 
    $or: [
        { updated_at: { $lt: ISODate("2018-06-01T00:00:00.000Z") } },
        { updated_at: { $not: { $type: 9 } } } 
    ] }, 
{ $set: { updated_at: ISODate("2018-06-01T00:00:00.000Z") } },
{ multi: true })
```

It simply checks `$lt` condition for dates defined and uses [$type](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/type/) to include all documents where type is not `Date`.

Comment: OK...I will try and update